# trying to install docker registry on fedora over digitalcloud

Tags: fedora, virtualization, digital-ocean, yum, docker-registry

I'm trying to install docker registry on fedora 24 by using this command:

```
yum install docker-registry
```

all I get is this output:

```
Yum command has been deprecated, redirecting to '/usr/bin/dnf install docker-registry'.
See 'man dnf' and 'man yum2dnf' for more information.
To transfer transaction metadata from yum to DNF, run:
'dnf install python-dnf-plugins-extras-migrate && dnf-2 migrate'

RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Free - Test Updates  483 kB/s | 242 kB     00:00
RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Nonfree              1.8 kB/s | 419  B     00:00
RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Free                 9.2 kB/s | 413  B     00:00
RPM Fusion for Fedora 24 - Nonfree - Test Updat 5.9 kB/s | 2.3 kB     00:00
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'dockerrepo', disabling.
Package docker-distribution-2.3.0-2.fc24.x86_64 is already installed, skipping.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
```

Can someone help me on this issue ?

Comment: Reading error messages as a service: `Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'dockerrepo', disabling.` seems like a problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is there is no official docker yum repository available as you can see here: https://yum.dockerproject.org/repo/main/fedora/

Docker 1.12 will add official support for Fedora 24, until then you can follow manual installation procedure